# extrema problem real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it true that global maximum of a convex function $f$ on $[a,b]$ must be attained at the boundary? prove it or provide a counterexample. Is it possible for $f$ to have a local maximum in $(a,b)$ ?

I know the answer intuitively, but I am not quiet sure how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\max_{[a,b]} f = f(c)$ for some $c \in (a,b).$ Because $f$ is continuous and convex on $[a,b],$ slopes of successive chords on the graph of $f$ increase as you move to the right. Thus

$$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \le \frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}.$$

The fraction on the left is $\ge 0,$ and the fraction on the right is $\le 0.$ Therefore both equal $0,$ which implies $f(a) = f(c)=f(b).$ This shows $\max f$ occurs on the boundary.

Comment: ok, so how about the second part: if it is possible for f to have  local maximum in (a,b)?

Comment: You can always let $f$ be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

A convex function is a continuous function whose value at the midpoint of every interval in its domain does not exceed the arithmetic mean of its values at the ends of the interval.

Now, suppose $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(c)\geq x \: \forall x\in [a,b]$. Then, $f(c) \geq f(a)$ and $f(c) \geq f(b)$ which implies that $2 \cdot f(c) \geq f(a)+f(b) \implies f(c) \geq \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ which, coupled with the definition of convex functions, implies that $f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$. As $f(c)$ is a global maxima, $f(c)=f(a)=f(b)$. So, the maxima global maxima must occur at the boundaries. An example might be the graph of $f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow [-1,0]; f(x)=-\left| sin(x) \right|$.

Comment: i don't quite understand why when f(c) is a maxima, f(c) = f(a) =f(b)?

Comment: @Dodge Because if it isn't, then $f(c)<f(a)$ or $f(c)<f(b)$. Which isn't possible as $f(c)$ is the global maxima.